# The friend who has the same dream

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases

Is there any phrase or just a word for a person (a friend or someone else) who has **the same dream (goal, purpose)** as someone else? How can I define it in English?

For instance:

> We both want to travel around the world by car.

Is the only way to call this person`"the friend who has the same dream"`?

Comment: By dream, do you mean goal in life? Like, you may both dream to be lawyers?

Comment: @simchona - you right. I meant goal, purpose in life.

Comment: If the best "goal in life" that two guys can come up with is to travel around the world by car (by implication, separately), perhaps they have the psychiatric syndrome [Folie à deux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Folie_%C3%A0_deux), otherwise known as *shared psychosis*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Interesting approach :) But how do you think, it is a psychiatric syndrome? Your comment is about only for my example, or general approach to having dream?

Comment: @dino: Well, I can understand a couple of guys wanting to go and do something like your example *together, for a finite amount of time*. But it does seem like a rather odd "life's ambition", which is what I assume you mean by *dream, goal, purpose*. Maybe if the ambition was *walk on the moon* I'd find it easier to understand two people just happening to have that same aspiration, without any special implication of wanting to do it together.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The word that will make this sound natural is "shared." For example, try any of the following:

"Ever since we were kids, we shared the dream of becoming lawyers."

"We shared the same dream of becoming a lawyer someday."

"Becoming a lawyer was always a dream we shared."

Comment: At first I thought a "shared dream" always implied *jointly and overtly* sharing the dream together in the past as well as the present. Then I realised that you can share the same dream as someone else even if you never meet them (which could apply in your examples 2/3).

Answer (score 4):

I think the prefix ***co-*** and the modifier ***fellow*** do better than *shared* to convey the idea of having identical aims without necessarily trying to achieve them together. (Though I'm not denying that *shared* can be used in that way.)

For travel or other recreational goals, a phrase like ***fellow enthusiast*** might do.

For more ambitious aims, perhaps something along the lines of ***co-aspirant*** would help. The latter isn't a standard phrase, but I think its meaning is perfectly clear.

Comment: "fellow dreamer" as someone with the same dream.

Comment: I thought about *dreamer*, too, of course, but the word tends to imply idealistic fantasies rather than life ambitions.

Answer (score 3):

'Comrade' might be closest to what you are looking for; people can use it to refer to someone in their same organization or group.

Of course, this just means you have an opportunity to get creative. I'm sure with a little thought, you could come up with something really evocative.

Comment: The use of *comrade* has [plummeted over the last century](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=comrade&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3), probably because of its connotations with authoritarian left-wing regimes.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think the story is [more complex than that](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=comrade%2C+Comrade&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3). The decrease in 'comrade' is associated with an increase in 'Comrade', which leads me to believe that it took on proper noun status. Additionally, 'Comrade' decreases in usage after 2000, and 'comrade' surges back.

Comment: I don't see how that makes it *more* complex. I'm sure an even higher proportion of the capitalised instances relate to authoritarian left-wing regimes. *Comrade Stalin*, and *Comrade Ogilvy* (in Orwell's *1984*) come to mind. My basic point is that the word is definitely "tainted" these days, although there are obviously some "positive" set phrases, such as [comrade in arms](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/comrade_in_arms)

Comment: @FumbleFingers It's not as simple as "usage of comrade has plummeted", as the graph plainly indicates that usage of big C "Comrade" increased at the same time that little c "comrade" decreased. And I agree that the increase in "Comrade" is probably do to phrases like "Comrade Stalin", that's kinda the point. Additionally, you left out 8 years from the graph, which shows that little usage of little c "comrade" is increasing in recent years. What this means, I'm not sure. I agree that the word might be tainted by its associations with Soviet Russia, but you can't just read that off the graph.

Comment: My starting point was my own "gut feel" that *comrade* was dated/tainted (capitalised or not). NGram seemed to me to confirm that, but to be honest I wouldn't set too much store by any such charts unless the patterns were overwhelming. Or if they agreed with my own preconceptions, obviously! :)

Answer (score 2):

The phrase "kindred spirits" also might be appropriate here. It means two people who are very similar in some way, for example, having similar goals, or having similar personalities.

Answer (score 0):

You can say you *share similar* or *common* goals, or you have *shared goals*.

Answer (score 0):

In this particular example, the phrase "fellow traveler" fits both in its literal meaning as well as its implied parlance. It means to want the same thing, even if you have different ways of going about it.